# How to handle 301 in app engine for php

Tags: php, .htaccess, google-app-engine, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a website in PHP hosted in GAE it's default url like https://websitename-1260.appspot.com. Now it's pointed to a domain like http://websitename.com and using Cname www.websitename.com it is www.websitename.com

SEO Consultant says For search bots website addresses with www and without it are considered as different pages. Adding redirection help you avoid double content panelty.

301 can be handle with .htaccess rules but I think in GAE it's not working. And in Google appspot.com url google is indexing : https://websitename-1260.appspot.com

I do not know how to solve it, we need both www and www less URl. So is there any easy solutions ? Below is my deployed yaml file.

```
application: websitename-1260
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|eot|svg|ttf|woff))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|eot|svg|ttf|woff))

- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /robots\.txt
  static_files: robots.txt
  upload: robots\.txt  

# Serve php scripts.
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```